# React router, компонент отрисовывается только при клике

Tags: react-router

Необходимо, чтобы при загрузке отрисовывалась главная страница, однако по умолчанию отрисовывается только хедер и уже после клика - домашняя страница или странички для входа/регистрации.
В чем может быть причина?

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Header />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/home" element={<Block />} />
      <Route path="/register" element={<SignUp />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<SignIn />} />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Скорее всего path при входе на страницу равен "/"

Comment: Так было изначально, но проблема была та же